# How to store the datepicker value into the table?

Tags: datetimepicker

### **Datetime date = Convert.ToDateTime(fmcollection[""]);** I have to use to convert the datetime but that line hit the error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime'

public ActionResult save( FormCollection fmcollection)
        {

```
        Datetime date = Convert.ToDateTime(fmcollection[""]);
```

/* insert code */
}

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in the line above and add a watch for `fmcollection[""]`, what is its value?

Comment: I cant run this because the error occured like Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'models.Datetime

Comment: So is the code not compiling at all, or is it crashing during execution? If it is crashing in the datetime conversion above, can you comment out that line and check what the value for `fmcollection[""]` is?